# How to convert decimal(16,4) to DATE or DATETIME in SQL or PHP

Tags: php, sql, date, decimal

I have a small problem with a field of my db... the submit time is in decimal(16,4) type and I need to convert it to DATE or DATETIME... but I dont get it...

One example:

```
decimal (16,4)         datetime
1334041225.5900        2012-04-10 09:00:25 +02:00
```

Comment: You say that your data is in your database, but this is tagged as PHP. Do you want to use these values as DATETIMEs within your SQL, or just extract them and use them as DATETIMEs in PHP? Also, which SQL implementation are you using? (MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Access?)

Answer (score 3):

This *appears* to be a unix timstamp with fractions of seconds, in which case....

```
print date('r', 1334041225.5900);
```

(it is possible that this numbering system intersects with Unix timestamps at 2012-04-10 09:00:25 +02:00).

See the manual page for the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for details of specifics.

It's prob ably possible to do the conversion in SQL but you didn't say what type of DBMS this is.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to insert the decimal u have to convert those decimal values into date format using this statements, echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1334041225.5900));

Answer (score 0):

in SQL       'select dateadd(ss, 1334041225.5900, '19700101')'