# PHP - Time from Decimal in hh::mm::ss

Tags: php, date

I have a decimal value: 1630.167 I can calculate the seconds of this, just by doing `1630.167 / 60` and rounding it up so that it gives me 27.1 seconds.

Is there a function within PHP that allows me to pass through a decimal value and covert to `hh::mm::ss` so in this case, it would give me the result of: `00::00::27` and the function would then return the correct value if say, the decimal would be a bigger number.

I am just looking to see whether or not there is a pre-defined function within PHP to do this..

Comment: I think this will work `date('H:i:s', strtotime(value))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal(16,4) to DATE or DATETIME in SQL or PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102749/how-to-convert-decimal16-4-to-date-or-datetime-in-sql-or-php)

Comment: @aldrin27 Will diff based on the server time, use `gmdate` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)-function like so:

```
$time = date('H::i::s', $value);
```

Works with doubles and floats too. Make sure you set your `date_default_timezone_set()` to the right timezone.

Comment: This answer is wrong, date is relative to the timezone setting and you should not make such a function rely on this. There are other functions and classes available that do the task in a correct matter. Also, date does not accept doubles or floats, they are cast to integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gmdate` which will allow you to pass seconds (unix time).

```
$seconds = 16000.43 / 60;
gmdate("H::i::s", $seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here....

```
echo  date('H:i:s', mktime(0,0,27));
```

O/P :: 00:00:27

give any number of seconds, it will give appropriate output in hh:mm:ss